# Pandas Get Other Row in Group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rank

Given the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d=pd.DataFrame({' ID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                'Benefit':['M','M','M','M','M','M','M','M'],
               'CED':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
               'CTD':[np.nan,np.nan,7,8,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
               'CED_Rank':[4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1],
               'CED_Max':[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]})
d
    ID  Benefit     CED     CED_Max     CED_Rank    CTD
0   1         M       1           4           4     NaN
1   1         M       2           4           3     NaN
2   1         M       3           4           2     7
3   1         M       4           4           1     8
4   2         M       1           4           4     NaN
5   2         M       2           4           3     NaN
6   2         M       3           4           2     NaN
7   2         M       4           4           1     NaN
```

CED_Max is the maximum CED value per group for ID and Benefit.

CED_Rank is the ranking of the CED value per group for ID and Benefit.

I would like to use the following conditions to update NaN values in the "CTD" column:
Within a row for a given ID and Benefit grouping:

1. if the CTD is null and
2. The CED is not equal to CED_Max

...then:

CTD should be equal to the CED of row with the next-highest CED_Rank value (highest rank = 1).

Here is the desired result:

```
    ID  Benefit     CED     CED_Max     CED_Rank    CTD
0   1         M       1           4           4     2
1   1         M       2           4           3     3
2   1         M       3           4           2     7
3   1         M       4           4           1     8
4   2         M       1           4           4     2
5   2         M       2           4           3     3
6   2         M       3           4           2     4
7   2         M       4           4           1     NaN
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using `shift`

Comment: also for this part 'The CED is not equal to CED_Max', you can over write it after `shift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .

```
d['CTD']=d.groupby('ID')['CTD'].fillna(d.CED.shift(-1))
# for The CED is not equal to CED_Max
# d.CTD[d.CED==(d.CED_Max)&d.CTD.isnull()]=np.nan or d['CTD']=np.where(d.CED==(d.CED_Max)&d.CTD.isnull(), np.nan, d.CTD)

Out[42]: 
  Benefit  CED  CED_Max  CED_Rank  CTD  ID
0       M    1        4         4  2.0   1
1       M    2        4         3  3.0   1
2       M    3        4         2  7.0   1
3       M    4        4         1  8.0   1
4       M    1        4         4  2.0   2
5       M    2        4         3  3.0   2
6       M    3        4         2  4.0   2
7       M    4        4         1  NaN   2
```